# Error with a form in Spring Boot using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, forms, thymeleaf

I started spring boot recently, and I'm trying to create a form to add a student to an API that I created.

It show me this error :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/add.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/add.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "add" - line 15, col 25)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "add" - line 15, col 25)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'age' of bean class [com.example.demo.model.Student]: Getter for property 'age' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:708)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:617)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.getValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:630)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.age" is null
    at com.example.demo.model.Student.getAge(Student.java:43) \
```

Here is my files :

My controller :

```
@GetMapping(value="/add")
public  String addStudentForm (Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("student",new Student());

    return "add"; 
}
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public String addStudentSubmit(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
    System.out.println(student.getLastname());
    return "addStudent";
}
```

My entity Student :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

public Student(long id, int age, String lastname, String surname, String mail, String course) {
    this.age=age;
    this.id=id;
    this.course=course;
    this.lastName= lastname;
    this.surname=surname;
    this.mail=mail;
    
}
public Student() {
    
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="surname")
private String surname;

private Integer age;
private String course;
private String mail;  

public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return this.surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname=surname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return this.lastName;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastName=lastname;
}

public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age=age;
}
public String getCourse() {
    return this.course;
}
public void setCourse(String course) {
    this.course=course;
}
public String getMail() {
    return this.mail;
}
public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail=mail;
}
```

}

StudentService :

```
   @Data
   @Service
   public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public Optional<Student> getStudentID(final Long id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Iterable<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void deleteStudent(final Long id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        Student savedStudent = studentRepository.save(student);
        return savedStudent;
    }

  }
```

Add.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Add a new student</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add a student</h1>
  <form action="#" th:object="${student}" th:action="@{/add}" method="post">
  <label>Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}" name="lastname"/>
  <label>First name:</label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}" name="surname" />
  <label>Age:</label>
  <input type="number" th:field="*{age}" name="age" />
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type="email" th:field="*{mail}" name="mail" />
  <label>Course:</label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{course}"  name="course"/>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

AddStudent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
   <title>Add a new student</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
   <p "'${student.lastname} + ${student.surname}" />
   <a href="/add">Add another student</a>
   <a href="/"> Return to home page </a>
```

I've been searching why since last week and I can't find a solution. 
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear in that age is null.  It is hard to tell without see what values are actually getting submitted by the form.  Are you sure an age value is being sent?

Comment: More specifically, `age` is a capital `I` `Integer` -- meaning that it can contain null values.  However, your getter returns a lowercase `i` `int`.  Java can't unbox a null `Integer` to an `int`, so you get the error `Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.age" is null`.  Either make the getter return an `Integer` or make sure that you never have a null `age`.

Comment: Thanks you for your help the problem was with the getter it worked with Integer and not int.

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because the 'age' property contains a value of 'null'.
when you have an input of type 'number', it needs a value, so thymeleaf is trying to get this value in the 'age' property of the 'student' object..

try inserting the 'min' and 'max' attributes in the input..

```
<input type="number" th:field="*{age}" min="1" max="100" />
```